# What is the proper way of forming required data object from an http response

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-6

I'm receiving a certain array from an api call and from that i need to form an array of objects. This is the array of objects i'm receiving from server

```
[
  {x:10,id:1,y:30},
  {x:10,id:2,y:50},
  {x:11,id:1,y:20},
  {x:11,id:2,y:70},
  {x:12,id:1,y:80},
  {x:12,id:2,y:90}
]
```

... and I need to convert it to:

```
[
  {x:10,id1:30,id2:50},
  {x:11,id2:20,id2:70},
  {x:12,id3:80,id2:90}
]
```

Basically storing the `y` part against their respective object

I've tried to generate the required object, but I had to use too many loops. Is there an easier or more accurate way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `reduce` is your friend

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
let arr=[ {x:10,id:1,y:30},
  {x:10,id:2,y:50},
  {x:11,id:1,y:20},
  {x:11,id:2,y:70},
  {x:12,id:1,y:80},
  {x:12,id:2,y:90}
]
let ans=[];
arr.forEach(o=>{
    if( !ans.find(i=>o.x===i.x)){
        let temp={x:o.x};
        temp[`id${o.id}`]=o.y;
        arr.filter(item=>(item.x===o.x && item.id!==o.id)).forEach((item,index)=>{
            temp[`id${item.id}`]=item.y;
        })
        ans.push(temp);
}
});
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Thanks thats an amazing answer and it did clear most of my concepts but what if we had no idea about the id . Meaning, where you applied if(o.id===1), what if the id in response is a random number. How to resolve it in that case

Comment: I think if the id is a random number the updated code will work

Comment: hey thanks i got it. One small question though what if there can be more than 2 id values (i.e id =1,id=2,id=3) is there way such that we can create the response array object accordingly meaning ({x:10,id1:30,id2:50,id3:"some value"})